# How do I calculate the surface area of a cone with a segment removed? (see picture)

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, surfaces

Suppose I have a cone with a segment removed, as shown in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIziU.png

I can assume all the cone dimensions are known, and that the plane intersecting the cone cutting it into the two sections is parallel to the axis of the cone. Then, I'd like to calculate the surface area of each of the **curved** sections (I don't need the surface areas of the flat sections). However, I'm not sure how to go about it, as the radial symmetry has been broken.

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your diagram shows the plane parallel not perpendicular to the axis of the cone...

Comment: The lateral area of the "sliced off" portion has the same ratio of lateral area / base area, as the entire cone.

Comment: you mean parallel to the axis ? also in the case of a vertical plane, the cross-section should be a triangle, though an hyperbola is shown on the picture.

Comment: @zwim. It should be a triangle only if the axis is included in the cutting plane.

Comment: This seems a general solution (but not verified)  https://www.academia.edu/30605701/Volume_and_surface_area_of_a_right_circular_cone_cut_by_a_plane_parallel_to_its_symmetrical_axis_Analysis_of_cut_cone_with_a_hyperbolic_section_

Comment: apologies, I meant parallel to the axis!

Comment: @DougM is there a proof for that? Thank you

Comment: @EmilioNovati thank you, that looks promising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the cone from a point of view parallel to the base.  There is a linear relationship between the slant length and the base radius.

And when we look as some section of the wall of the cone, there is a corresponding projection on the base.  And the difference in the area is proportional to this $\frac {\text {slant length}}{\text {radius}} = \sec \theta$ ratio.

One factor of distance has been dilated in a linear way, so area has been dilated by the same factor.

If you know multivariate calculus I can show you that way, too.